# Openshift php app not working

Tags: php, openshift, redhat, openshift-php-cartidges

I have created a PHP app with git repo. In my aacount it shows that app has started but when I go to the website it shows "Not Found"
(http://ebookstack-niraliacharya.rhcloud.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the app and again created using command line tools and voila!! It was created successfully and also the error "Not found" was replaced with "Welcome to your PHP application on OpenShift".